# If $F(x+y,x/y)=0$ for $F$ smooth and $(x,y)$ in any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $F=0$ on an open subset.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

I came across the following statement in Olver's "Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations". Paraphrasing:

> Let $\xi^1(x,y)=x+y$, $\xi^2(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$, and $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which does not contain the line $y\ne 0$. For any smooth (infinitely differentiable) $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, if $F\left(\xi^1(x,y),\xi^2(x,y)\right)=0$ for $(x,y)\in U$, then there exists an open subset of $V=\left(\xi^1(U),\xi^2(U)\right)$ such that $F(V)=0$.

Apparently this follows through an application of the inverse function theorem, but I can't see how to make this work.

Comment: If the Jacobian determinant of $\xi = (\xi^1,\xi^2)$ is non-zero, then $\xi$ maps a nonempty open set to a nonempty open set (by the inverse function theorem).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Since $d\xi$ is non-zero, there exists an open set $U_0\subset U$, $\xi(U_0)=V_0\subset V$ where $V_0$ is open, and $F(V_0)=0$.

Comment: Nonsingular — much stronger than nonzero.